# "Signature verification failed" error while creating an account

Tags: anchor, account, signature, typescript

I am trying to create an account but I get an error while creating it.

```
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider); 

const newAccountKeypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.generate();

const create_account_instruction = anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
  fromPubkey: provider.wallet.publicKey,
  newAccountPubkey: newAccountKeypair.publicKey,
  space: 1000000,
  lamports: lamports,
  programId: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId, 
});

const createAccountTransaction = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(create_account_instruction)
const latestBlockhash = await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
createAccountTransaction.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
const createAccountResult = await provider.sendAndConfirm(createAccountTransaction);
```

Provider in this example is AnchorProvider but I don't think it's related with it. I've tried with Phantom and got same error.

sendAndConfirm method description:

> “Sends the given transaction, paid for and signed by the provider's
> wallet.”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to also pass the keypair for newAccountPubkey as a signer. The sendAndConfirm method should have an array for signers you can use for this.

This will also mean creating a variable for the key pair and using the someKeypair.pubkey property on the Keypair object.

Comment: Yeah, I think he needs to specify the fee payer on createAccountTransaction: Transaction using the feePayer property.

Something like 

createAccountTransaction.feePayer = provider.wallet.publicKey;

Comment: Thank you. Problem is solved when I added newAccountKeypair as signer in sendAndConfirm.

Comment: Thanks to T.J. Littlejohn I added  signers: [user], to   
`{
   accounts: {
    user: user.publicKey,
    authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        // clock: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_CLOCK_PUBKEY,
   },
   signers: [user],
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah when you're creating new accounts with "throwaway" keypairs like this that keypair needs to sign the initial instruction as well. I've seen this with stake accounts but I assume it'd be the same with regular ATAs.